# Understanding the reason why my while loop is breaking

Tags: python, function, loops

I have a project to create a Battleships game in Python. The code I'm working on right now checks the user's input coordinates to make sure they're not out of range. If the coordinates are out of range, the `while` loop should just loop back around to the start, give the user an error message and tell them to enter the coordinates again. For whatever reason, this is not happening.

The code that calls the function:

```
def startGame():
    if DEBUG == True:
        print("startGame Called from main loop")
    userBoard = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
    print("This is your game board:\n")
    printOneArray(userBoard)
    input("Press Enter to continue:\n>>> ")
    userBoard = setupUserArray(userBoard)
    printOneArray(userBoard)
    input()
```

The function itself so far (note that there's nothing actually there telling it to break yet):

```
def setupUserArray(arr):
    print("You have 5 ships:\n - The Aircraft Carrier (1x5)\n - The Battleship (1x4)\n - The Submarine (1x3)\n - The Destroyer (1x3)\n - The Patrol Boat (1x2)\n")
    for i in range(5):
        if i == 0:
            print("Now to place The Aircraft Carrier:")
        if i == 1:
            print("Now to place The Battleship:")
        if i == 2:
            print("Now to place The Submarine:")
        if i == 3:
            print("Now to place The Destroyer:")
        if i == 4:
            print("Now to place The Patrol Boat:")
        while True:
            direction = input("Would you like to place it horizontally or vertically?\t(V for vertically, H for horizontally)\n>>> ")
            if (direction == "V") or (direction == "v") or (direction == "H") or (direction == "h"):
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid Input!")
        while True:
            printOneArray(arr)
            inputx = input("Please Enter the Coordinates you wish to place the ship on:\nx = ")
            inputy = input("y = ")
            try:
                int(inputx)
                int(inputy)
            except:
               print("input is not an integer!")
            if (inputx > 9) or (inputx < 0) or (inputy > 9) or (inputy < 0):
               print("Input exceeds the coordinates!")
```

The `printOneArray` function:

```
def printOneArray(arr):
    r = 0
    c = 0
    for r in range(10):
        print((9-r), " ", end = "") #SELF REMINDER TO UNJANK THE INPUT COORDINATES WHEN SOMEBODY ENTERS THEM, PROBABLY ONLY FOR ROWS THO
        for c in range(10):
            print(arr[r][c], " " , end = "")
        print("")
    print("\n   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9\n")
```

No matter what the user enters, the `setupUserArray()` function just skips over to the main menu function for no apparent reason and completely ignores the rest of the `startGame()` function.

What is the reason?

Comment: Do you get any error messages when you run this code? Because I get one, and it tells me what is wrong with the program.

Comment: @mkrieger1 what error message are you recieving? because I'm not getting any.

Comment: I get: `File "ships.py", line 42, in setupUserArray
    if (inputx > 9) or (inputx < 0) or (inputy > 9) or (inputy < 0):
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()`

Comment: And the reason for this is that you need to assign `int(inputx)` and `int(inputy)` back to `inputx` and `inputy`, respectively.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Thanks for specifying. Which version of python are you running on? I'm using 3.6.5

Comment: I use Python 3.5.3, but that should not make a difference.

Comment: @mkrieger1 so something like this?
`int(inputx) = input("Please Enter the Coordinates you wish to place the ship on:\nx = ")
int(inputy) = input("y = ")`

Comment: No, `inputx = int(inputx)` instead of just `int(inputx)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mkrieger pointed out, you need to assign `inputx` and `inputy` the types as follows:

```
    while True:
        printOneArray(arr)
        inputx = input("Please Enter the Coordinates you wish to place the ship on:\nx = ")
        inputy = input("y = ")
        try:
            inputx = int(inputx)
            inputy = int(inputy)
        except:
            print("input is not an integer!")
            break
        if (inputx > 9) or (inputx < 0) or (inputy > 9) or (inputy < 0):
            print("Input exceeds the coordinates!")
```

I know this is not a code review, but personally I'd still refactor your code as follows:

```
def input_direction(string):
    direction = input(string)
    # vertical, vert, V, v all get converted to "V"
    # horizontal, hor, H, v all get converted to "H"
    direction = direction.upper()[0]
    if direction in "HV":
        return direction.upper()
    print("Please enter a direction by entering either V or H")
    return input_direction(string)


def input_number(string):
    number = input(string)
    try:
        number = int(number)
        if number in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]:
            return number
    except TypeError:
        print("Please enter a single numeric digit")
        return input_number(string)
```

It would be used like this:

```
def setupUserArray(arr):
    print("You have 5 ships:")
    print("- The Aircraft Carrier (1x5)")
    print("- The Battleship (1x4)")
    print("- The Submarine (1x3)")
    print("- The Destroyer (1x3)")
    print("- The Patrol Boat (1x2)")
    for i in ["Aircraft Carrier", "Battleship", "Submarine", "Destroyer", "Patrol Boat"]:
        print("Now to place The", i)
        direction = input_direction("Would you like to place it horizontally or vertically?\t(V for vertically, H for horizontally)\n>>> ")
        print("Please Enter the Coordinates you wish to place the ship on:")
        inputx = input_digit("Enter the desired X coordinate")
        inputy = input_digit("Enter the desired Y coordinate")


def input_direction(string):
    direction = input(string)
    # vertical, vert, V, v all get converted to "V"
    # horizontal, hor, H, v all get converted to "H"
    direction = direction.upper()[0]
    if direction in "HV":
        return direction.upper()
    print("Please enter a direction by entering either V or H")
    return input_direction(string)


def input_digit(string):
    number = input(string)
    try:
        number = int(number)
        if number in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]:
            return number
    except TypeError:
        print("Please enter a single numeric digit")
        return input_digit(string)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips on making my code more optimal. I looked at the error the mkrieger1 got and searched that up, ended up getting the code to work again.

Comment: No problems, Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, my interpreter wasn't giving me any errors.
But using the error that @mkrieger1 provided me with, I was able to make the code work.
The error was that Python was attempting to compare a string to an integer, which would cause undefined behaviour in my case, and an error in his. Here is the code I used to make sure that the integer was compared to another integer:

```
        while True:
        printOneArray(arr)
        inputx = input("Please Enter the Coordinates you wish to place the ship on:\nx = ")
        inputy = input("y = ")
        try:
            int(inputx)
            int(inputy)
        except:
            print("input is not an integer!")
        if (int(inputx) > 9) or (int(inputx) < 0) or (int(inputy) > 9) or (int(inputy) < 0):
            print("Input exceeds the coordinates!")
```